# How can I Optimize this trigger for more than 1000 records insertion

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I write a trigger on Contact which maintains the sequence number for newly inserted records Now I want to make to run for more the 1000 for multiple accounts can someone suggest me the changes what can I do to achieve the bulkiness.

```
public void beforeInsert(List<Contact> newConTrigger){
    isFirstTime = false;
    conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
        //  System.debug('The c is ' + c);
        conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
        
    }
    if(conAcctsIdSet.size()>0){
        conWithAcctsList = [Select Id,(Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By sequence_number__c ASC) from Account where Id IN:conAcctsIdSet];
        for(Account accts: conWithAcctsList){
            conListOld = new List<Contact>();
            conWithList = new List<Contact>();
            conList = new List<Contact>();
            conMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
            for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
                if(c.AccountId == accts.id){
                    conWithList.add(c);
                }
            }                
            if(accts.contacts.size()>0){
                for(Contact conRec : accts.contacts){
                    conMap.put((Integer)conRec.Sequence_Number__c,conRec);//fillig the with old values
                }
                System.debug('the old cons are ' + accts.contacts);
                conListOld.addAll(accts.contacts);// 1 2 3      1 2 
                System.debug('the conMap is 0'+conMap);
                addRecords(conWithList,accts.id);
                for(Contact c : conMap.values()){//now our Map is Updated with old and new values with specified and ordered sq no now extract only old contacts from the map to the list and update that list
                    if(conListOld.contains(c)){
                        conList.add(c);
                    }
                }     
            }    
            else{
                System.debug('Elsepart');
                addRecords(conWithList,accts.id);
            }
            
            if(conList.size()>0){
                update conList;
            }
        }
    } 
    
}

/*=====================================Filling the Map with new and Old values ============================================================*/
public void addRecords(List<Contact> newContacts,Id accId){
    for(Contact c : newContacts){
        Integer val = (Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c;
        if(accId == c.AccountId && conMap.containsKey(val)){
            for(Integer i = conMap.size()+1;i>val;i--){
                conMap.get(i-1).Sequence_Number__c = i; // Periodically shifting the seq of each rec by one from last upto current seq num
                conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i-1));
            }
            conMap.put((Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c,c);
        }
        else{
            // c1-1  c2-2  c3-1   c4-2  c5-1 --->>  c1-1,c2-2 -- c3-1,c1-2,c2-3 --- c3-1,c4-2,c1-3,c2-4 -->>#   (c5-1,c3-2,c4-3,c1-4,c2-5)
            c.Sequence_Number__c = conMap.size()+1;//In starting the size of map is ZERO so initialize the first record by number 1 Bydefault
            conMap.put((Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c , c);//Put that rec in the map and size become 0+1(In first Step)
        }
        System.debug('The Map is ::' + conMap);
    }          
}
```

This is the query I want to execute

```
    List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
for(Integer i = 1;i<=500;i++){
    con.add(new Contact(LastName = 'k' + i,AccountId = '0015j00000WjZJd',sequence_number__c = i ));
    con.add(new Contact(LastName = 'l' + i,AccountId = '0015j00000WjZVP',sequence_number__c = i ));
   // con.add(new Contact(LastName = 'm' + i,AccountId = '0015j00000WlEEJ',sequence_number__c = i ));
}
insert con;
```

This  is the Error

```
System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded
```

Full Code of Trigger::-

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {
List<Contact> conList;//It holds the records on which we have to apply DML
List<Contact> conListOld;//It holds the old records 
Set<Contact> setContacts = new Set<Contact>();//It hold the Id's of the Account 
List<Contact> conListNew = new List<Contact>();//It holds the records of new 
List<Contact> conWithList;//It holds the records of particular account's contact record
public static Boolean isFirstTime = true;
public Map<Integer,Contact> conMap;
Set<ID> conAcctsIdSet;//This set will hold the ID of Account which is related with the contact
List<Account> conWithAcctsList = new List<Account>();
/*=============================================BEFORE INSERT CASE ===========================================================*/
public void beforeInsert(List<Contact> newConTrigger){
    isFirstTime = false;
    conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
        //  System.debug('The c is ' + c);
        conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
        
    }
    if(conAcctsIdSet.size()>0){
        conWithAcctsList = [Select Id,(Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By sequence_number__c ASC) from Account where Id IN:conAcctsIdSet];
         conList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account accts: conWithAcctsList){
            conListOld = new List<Contact>();
            conWithList = new List<Contact>();
            conMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
            //conList.clear();
            for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
                if(c.AccountId == accts.id){
                    conWithList.add(c);
                }
            }                
            if(accts.contacts.size()>0){
                for(Contact conRec : accts.contacts){
                    conMap.put((Integer)conRec.Sequence_Number__c,conRec);//fillig the with old values
                }
                System.debug('the old cons are ' + accts.contacts);
                conListOld.addAll(accts.contacts);// 1 2 3      1 2 
                System.debug('the conMap is 0'+conMap);
                addRecords(conWithList,accts.id);
                for(Contact c : conMap.values()){//now our Map is Updated with old and new values with specified and ordered sq no now extract only old contacts from the map to the list and update that list
                    if(conListOld.contains(c)){
                        conList.add(c);
                    }
                }     
            }    
            else{
                System.debug('Elsepart');
                addRecords(conWithList,accts.id);
            }               
        }
        if(conList.size()>0){
            update conList;
        }
        
    } 
   
    
}

/*=====================================Filling the Map with new and Old values ============================================================*/
public void addRecords(List<Contact> newContacts,Id accId){
    for(Contact c : newContacts){
        Integer val = (Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c;
        if(accId == c.AccountId && conMap.containsKey(val)){
            for(Integer i = conMap.size()+1;i>val;i--){
                conMap.get(i-1).Sequence_Number__c = i; // Periodically shifting the seq of each rec by one from last upto current seq num
                conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i-1));
            }
            conMap.put((Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c,c);
        }
        else{
            // c1-1  c2-2  c3-1   c4-2  c5-1 --->>  c1-1,c2-2 -- c3-1,c1-2,c2-3 --- c3-1,c4-2,c1-3,c2-4 -->>#   (c5-1,c3-2,c4-3,c1-4,c2-5)
            c.Sequence_Number__c = conMap.size()+1;//In starting the size of map is ZERO so initialize the first record by number 1 Bydefault
            conMap.put((Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c , c);//Put that rec in the map and size become 0+1(In first Step)
        }
        System.debug('The Map is ::' + conMap);
    }          
} 




/*=========================================================== AFTER DELETION CASE =======================================================================================*/
public void afterDelete(List<Contact> deletedCon){//the record which is recently deleted by which trigger is fired
    isFirstTime = false;
    conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    System.debug('the deleting list is  :: '+deletedCon.size());
    List<Contact> cu = new  List<Contact>([Select Sequence_number__c from contact where Accountid  ='0015j00000WjZJd']);
    System.debug('the c is :: ' + cu);
    //map<id,Contact> conmap = new map<id,Contact>();
    for(Contact c : deletedCon){
        conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
    }
    if(conAcctsIdSet.size()>0){
        conWithAcctsList = [Select Id, (Select Id,AccountId, Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By sequence_number__c ASC) from Account where id in :conAcctsIdSet];//Master Accounts to which contacts are associated
        conList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account acc : conWithAcctsList){
            for(Contact conRec : acc.Contacts){
                if(conRec.AccountId == acc.id){
                    conRec.Sequence_Number__c = 1;
                    conList.add(conRec);
                }
            }
            deleteRecords(conList,acc.Id);   
        }    
    }        
}    
public void deleteRecords(List<Contact> cnList,Id accId){//cnList contains all the contacts associated with the current object
    conMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
    for(Contact cc : cnList){
        if(cc.AccountId == accId){
            //First fill the map with seq no contacts
            Integer val =(Integer)cc.sequence_Number__c;//fetching the first contact seq number into the val variable
            if(!conMap.containsKey(val)){
                val = (Integer)cc.sequence_Number__c;
                conMap.put(val,cc);
            }
            else{
                while(conMap.containsKey(val)){
                    val++;
                }
                cc.sequence_Number__c = val;      
                conMap.put((Integer)cc.sequence_Number__c,cc);
            }
        } 
    }
    if(conMap.values().size()>0){
        update conMap.values();
    }
}
/*============================================ AFTER UNDELETE CASE ==================================================*/
public void afterUndelete(List<Contact> newConTrigger){
    isFirstTime = false;
    conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : newConTrigger){
        conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
    }
    if(conAcctsIdSet.size()>0){
        conWithAcctsList = [Select Id, (Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By sequence_number__c ASC) from Account where id in :conAcctsIdSet];
        conList = new List<Contact>();
        conWithList = new List<Contact>();
        conWithList = [select Id,sequence_number__c,AccountId from contact where AccountId IN : conAcctsIdSet AND ID IN :newConTrigger];
        for(Account accts : conWithAcctsList ){
            List<Contact> tempList = new List<Contact>();
            for(Contact c  : conWithList){
                if(c.AccountId == accts.id){
                    tempList.add(c);
                }
            }
            Integer size = accts.contacts.size() - tempList.size();
            for(Contact c : tempList){
                c.Sequence_Number__c = size + 1;
                size++;
                conList.add(c);
            }  
        }     
    }   
    if(conList.size()>0){
        update conList;
    }
}

public map<Integer,Contact> newConMap;
public map<Id,Integer> oldConMap;
/*===============================================================AFTER TRIGGER================================================================================================*/
public void beforeUpdate(List<Contact> conNewTrigger){
    if(isFirstTime){    
        conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact c : conNewTrigger){
            conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
        }
        if(!conAcctsIdSet.isEmpty()){
            conWithAcctsList = [Select Id, (Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By sequence_number__c ASC) from Account where id in :conAcctsIdSet];
            for(Account accts : conWithAcctsList){
                newConMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
                conMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
                conWithList = new List<Contact>();
                conListOld = new List<Contact>();
                oldConMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
                /*First fill the Map witht the old values before updated values*/
                for(Contact cc : accts.contacts){
                    conListOld.add(cc);
                    oldConMap.put(cc.id,(Integer)cc.sequence_number__c);
                    conMap.put((Integer)cc.Sequence_Number__c,cc);
                }
                
                System.debug('the id is' + conNewtrigger);
                for(Contact cc : conNewTrigger){
                    if(cc.AccountId == accts.id){
                        newConMap.put((Integer)cc.Sequence_Number__c,cc);
                        conWithList.add(cc); 
                    }
                }
                //Now Map is filled with the old values Now iterate the updated contacts
                updateRecords(conWithList,conMap,conListOld,newConMap,oldConMap);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*==================================== UPDATE RECORDS METHOD TO UPDATE ALL EXISTING RECORD AS PER THE UPDATED RECORDS ==========================*/
public void updateRecords(List<Contact> conWithList,Map<Integer,Contact> conMap,List<Contact> conListOld,Map<Integer,Contact> newConMap,Map<Id,Integer> oldConMap){   
    Set<Id> idsOfNewContacts = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : conWithList){
        idsOfNewContacts.add(c.id);
        Integer updatedSeqNo = (Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c;
        Integer oldSeqNo = oldConMap.get(c.id);
        if(conMap.containskey(updatedSeqNo)){
            System.debug('inside ##$#$#4');
            if(updatedSeqNo > oldSeqNo && updatedSeqNo <= conMap.size()){
                for(Integer i = oldSeqNo;i<updatedSeqNo;i++){
                    System.debug('the seq no is ' + conMap.get(i).sequence_Number__C + 'AND con is ' + conMap.get(i).id);
                    conMap.get(i+1).sequence_number__C = i;
                    conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i+1));
                }
                conMap.put(updatedSeqNo,c);
                for(contact keys : conMap.values()){
                    oldConMap.put(keys.id,(Integer)keys.Sequence_Number__c);
                }
            }
            if(updatedSeqNo < oldSeqNo && updatedSeqNo > 0){
                for(Integer i = oldSeqNo;i > updatedSeqNo;i--){
                    conMap.get(i-1).sequence_number__C = i;
                    conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i-1));
                }
                conMap.put(updatedSeqNo,c);
                for(contact keys : conMap.values()){
                    oldConMap.put(keys.id,(Integer)keys.Sequence_Number__c);
                }
            }      
        }
        else{
            /**NULL NEGATIVE ZERO OUTOFBOUND CASE**/
            for(Integer i = oldSeqNo;i<conMap.size();i++){
                conMap.get(i+1).Sequence_Number__c = i;
                conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i+1));
            }
            c.sequence_number__C = conMap.size();
            conMap.put(conMap.size(),c);
            for(contact keys : conMap.values()){
                oldConMap.put(keys.id,(Integer)keys.Sequence_Number__c);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    /*Separate the new values from the old values from the conMap by using old's Ids*/
    for(Id id : idsOfNewContacts){
        conMap.remove(oldConMap.get(id));
    }
    isFirstTime = false;
    update conMap.values(); 
}
```

}

Comment: firstly you could move the update conList dml statement out of the loop. Just keep adding to the list and do the entire dml update after the Account loop.

Comment: please use [edit] and give an example or two of what you want to achieve. Also, can the work be delegated to async (which has greater limits)?

Comment: the error you are getting could be triggered by any code running on the Contact object. Can you post your entire trigger code?

Comment: Sure..............................

Comment: have you found out yet where the limit is wrt number of records being inserted? I have the feeling you are getting into an infinite loop somewhere. Maybe you could study the debug logs to see what's going on exactly.

Comment: It is working for one Account for 1200 records and for two accounts limit is only 500 but I want 1000 limit for multiple account.
And the loop is not iterating for infinite time.